Dropdown multiselect
Couldn't select again when show selected data form api (to select again taglist)
Here is code
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: SfColors.primary500,
        ),
        titleSpacing: 0,
        title: Text(
          'Stream Setup',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: SfColors.primary500,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
        ),
      ),
      body: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => updateStreamInfoBloc!,
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => getStreamInfoBloc!
              ..add(GetGetStreamInfos(
                loginUserId: loginUserId,
              )),
          )
        ],
        child: BlocConsumer<GetStreamInfoBloc, GetStreamInfoState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is GetStreamInfoLoading) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (state is GetStreamInfoSuccess) {
              //streamInfo = state.allGetStreamInfos;

              if (streamInfo != null) {
                titleController.text = streamInfo!.title ?? '';
                pinMessageController.text = streamInfo!.pinMessage ?? '';
                categoryName = streamInfo!.categoryName ?? '';
                selectedTagNames =
                    streamInfo!.tag?.map((tag) => tag.tagName!).toList() ?? [];
                selectedTagIds =
                    streamInfo!.tag!.map((tag) => tag.tagID!).toList();
              }

              return Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
                child: Column(
                  // alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                          SFTextFieldWidget(
                            titleText: 'Title',
                            textAboutMe: false,
                            hintText: 'Title your Stream',
                            textEditingController: titleController,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                         

                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text('Tag',
                                    style:
                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge),
                                       
                                BlocConsumer<TagListBloc, TagListState>(
                                  builder: (context, state) {
                                    if (state is TagListLoading) {
                                      return const SizedBox(
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      );
                                    } else if (state is TagListSuccess) {
                                      tagList = state.allTagLists!.map((item) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                                          value: item.tagName,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              if (selectedTagNames
                                                  .contains(item.tagName))
                                                Icon(Icons.check,
                                                    color: SfColors.primary500),
                                              const SizedBox(width: 8),
                                              Text(item.tagName ?? ""),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }).toList();

                                      return Row(
                                        children: [
                                         
                                           Expanded(
                                            child:
                                                DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                              isExpanded: true,
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                                color: SfColors.primary500,
                                              ),
                                              hint: Text(
                                                selectedTagNames.isEmpty
                                                    ? 'Tag'.tr()
                                                    : selectedTagNames
                                                        .join(', '),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color:
                                                        SfColors.achromatic700),
                                              ),
                                              items: tagList,
                                              onChanged: (item) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  if (selectedTagNames
                                                      .contains(item)) {
                                                    final index =
                                                        selectedTagNames
                                                            .indexOf(item!);
                                                    selectedTagNames
                                                        .remove(item);
                                                    selectedTagIds
                                                        .removeAt(index);
                                                  } else {
                                                    final selectedItem = state
                                                        .allTagLists!
                                                        .firstWhere((tag) =>
                                                            tag.tagName ==
                                                            item);
                                                    selectedTagNames.add(item!);
                                                    selectedTagIds
                                                        .add(selectedItem.id!);
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              },
                                              value: null,
                                              selectedItemBuilder:
                                                  (BuildContext context) {
                                                return tagList!.map<Widget>(
                                                    (DropdownMenuItem<String>
                                                        item) {
                                                  return Text(
                                                    selectedTagNames.isEmpty
                                                        ? 'Tag'.tr()
                                                        : selectedTagNames
                                                            .join(', '),
                                                  );
                                                }).toList();
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return const Center(child: Text(""));
                                    }
                                  },
                                  listener: (context, state) {
                                    if (state is TagListFail) {
                                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                              content: Text(state.message)));
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          SFTextFieldWidget(
                            titleText: 'Pin Message',
                            textAboutMe: true,
                            height: 160,
                            hintText: 'Pin Message',
                            textEditingController: pinMessageController,
                          ),
                          BlocConsumer<UpdateStreamInfoBloc,
                              UpdateStreamInfoState>(
                            listener: (context, state) {
                              if (state is UpdateStreamInfoFailed) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    SnackBar(content: Text(state.message)));
                              } else if (state is UpdateStreamInfoSuccess) {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(
                                  context,
                                  '/live_page',
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            builder: (context, state) {
                              if (state is UpdateStreamInfoLoading) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 40,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            color:
                                                Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              } else {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    
                                    context
                                        .read<UpdateStreamInfoBloc>()
                                        .add(UpdateStreamInfoIn(
                                          title: titleController.text,
                                          categoryID: categoryId ??
                                              streamInfo?.categoryID ??
                                              0,
                                          userID: loginUserId!,
                                          pinMessage: pinMessageController.text,
                                          tagIds: selectedTagIds,
                                          privacy: '1',
                                        ));
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 14.0, right: 14),
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 40,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: SfColors.primary500,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Next",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ]))),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: Text("Loading...."),
              );
            }
          },
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is GetStreamInfoFail) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.message)));
            } else if (state is GetStreamInfoSuccess) {
              setState(() {
                streamInfo = state.allGetStreamInfos;
              });
            } else if (state is GetStreamInfoLoading) {}
          },
        ),
        //),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I want to multiselect with dropdown in all situation.
First select data and send data to backend. And then need to get that selected data from api and show at UI.Finally edit and update with multiselect.
Need to send update select tag id like [2,3]
dropdown taglist api response was
`data
: 
[{ID: 1, tagName: "Ball", description: null, created_at: null, updated_at: null},…]
0
: 
{ID: 1, tagName: "Tennis", description: null, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
ID
: 
1
created_at
: 
null
description
: 
null
tagName
: 
"RPG Ball"
updated_at
: 
null
1
: 
{ID: 2, tagName: "PinPIn", description: null, created_at: null, updated_at: null}
2
: 
{ID: 3, tagName: "MOB", description: null, created_at: null, updated_at: null}`

Here is get selected data from api response
`data
: 

: 
{ID: 22, userID: 22,  categoryID: 3, title: "yyy",…}
ID
: 
22
categoryID
: 
3
categoryName
: 
"Tennis Ball"
created_at
: 
"2024-05-15T04:48:12.000Z"
deleted_at
: 
null
followerOnlyChat
: 
null
pinMessage
: 
"pin message"
privacySetting
: 
1
s3categoryImage
: 
"https://Storage/images.jpeg"

tags
: 
[{ID: 329, streaminfoID: 22, tagID: 3, created_at: "2024-06-06T05:39:47.000Z",…},…]
title
: 
"yyy"
updated_at
: 
"2024-06-06T05:39:47.000Z"
userID
: 
22`

